# How to scroll in windows 8 app using mouse gesture?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, windows

I have created a app which needed to scroll horizontally for that i use  but i want that when the mouse reach to the side of the screen then the scrolling will be done automatically on the respective sides where the mouse went.

Comment: I don't know why are you doing this. but it will not be a good user experience. Scroll has been given for mouse to do scrolling and users know that.

Comment: But I need to scroll using mouse gesture also... Like in case of windows home screen.